# Linear Algebra: Sum of Subspaces is also subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working through Axler’s “Linear Algebra Done Right”, and it asks the reader to verify that if
$$
U_1,...,U_m
$$ 
are subspaces of $V$, a vector space over $F$, a field either $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$, then the sum of the subspaces
$$
U_1 + \dots + U_m = \{u_1 + \dots + u_m : u_1 \in U_1, \dots , u_m \in U_m \}
$$
is a subspace of $V$:

I feel intuition for why this should be true, but am unable to feel confident that I can rigorously prove that it is a the sum is a subspace. Could someone post a link to a proof (preferable) or prove it:

I. the sum is a subset of $V$;

II. the sum contains the additive identity (I think I have this one; each subset will have an additive identity, since it is a vector space, and there will be a possible sum of only additive identities, thus the sum will contain the additive identity of $V$.);

III. the sum is closed under addition;

IV. the sum is closed under scalar multiplication,

and thus proving the sum is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Why don't you try to prove it yourself.  Then when/ if you get stuck we can better help you.

Comment: I have tried for an hour or more to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. $U_1+...+U_m \subseteq V$ by the vector space (additive) closure axiom for $V$

II. For each $U_i$, $0 \in U_i$ since $U_i$ is a subspace, so $0+...+0=0 \in U_1+...+U_m$.

III. Take $u_1+...+u_m, v_1+...+v_m \in U_1+...+U_m$. Then: $u_1+...+u_m+v_1+...+v_m=(u_1+v_1)+...+(u_m+v_m)$ by commutativity. $u_i + v_i \in U_i$ by additive closure of $U_i$, since $U_i$ is a subspace, thus $(u_1+v_1)+...+(u_m+v_m) \in U_1+...U_m$.

IV. Take $a \in F$. Then $au_1+...+au_m \in U_1+...+U_m$, since $au_i \in U_i$ since $U_i$ is a subspace. Then by definition $au_1+...+au_m=a(u_1+...+u_m) \in U_1+...+U_m$.

Comment: I do know know what the closure axiom or the additive closure are; I assume they are later content?

Comment: Additive closure axiom: $a,b \in V$ implies $a+b \in V$. 
Scalar multiplication: $v \in V, a \in F$ implies $av \in V$.
These are fundamental to defining vector spaces, you should learn these as they are the basis to proving many things concerning vector spaces. There are I believe 6 more axioms as well.

Comment: My book says that you need to "check" (prove) that a,b∈V implies a+b∈V, and  v∈V,a∈F implies av∈V to verify that V is a subspace of some vector space

Comment: Right, and we proved that above. We are given that $U_i$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$ and as such must satisfy those axioms. We then used those axioms above to prove that $U_1+...+U_m$ also satisfies those axioms and hence is also a subspace.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Some of my confusion was because my book did not present these as axioms but as if these properties hold, then it is a vector space;... as conditions necessary for it to be a vector space; I guess that is axiom-like. I think I understand! It hadn't occurred to me to use the 'closure' properties/ axioms of the vector spaces containing the subspaces or of the subspaces containing the vectors.